# ASP.NET MVC3 Controller Method route variable parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way to route a variable set of parameters to an MVC3 controller.

I'm trying to get something to match a url like

```
/myaction/foo
or 
/myaction/foo/bar/widget/.../foo1/foo2/ - i.e. of unknown length.
```

at the moment I'm faking it with

```
public ActionResult myaction(string f1, string f2, string f3, string f4) 
{ 
}
```

and a route

```
 routes.MapRoute("brittleroute",
            "myaction/{f1}/{f2}/{f3}/{f4}",
            new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction", f1 = UrlParameter.Optional, f2=UrlParameter.Optional, f3=UrlParameter.Optional, f4=UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

but that is horribly brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging and some offline help...

```
public ActionResult myaction(string allsegments)
{
    var urlsegments = allsegments.split('/');
    //...
}


routes.MapRoute("betterroute",
        "myaction/{*allsegments}",
        new { controller = "mycontroller", action = "myaction"}
        );
```